# Can I install CUDA 5.0 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, cuda

I am currently on Ubuntu 14.04 and require CUDA 5.0.

However, it seems CUDA 5.0 is available only for Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.10 based on the download page: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-50-archive

I am wondering if I download CUDA 5.0 for Ubuntu 10.04, will work on my Ubuntu 14.04? Or is it not possible to have CUDA 5.0 with Ubuntu 14.04?

Many Thanks

Comment: Don't think so. You may need [CUDA 7](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) instead.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks, there is a package I am trying to use that specifically required CUDA 5.0. Maybe I'll throw up a VM with up Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: are you sure it didn't ask for cuda >=5.0 (note the greater than **or** equal to)?

Comment: @mchid It states "CUDA Toolkit 5.0", the package is a machine learning library that can use the GPU: http://sourceforge.net/projects/currennt/files/?source=navbar (the "Building on Linux" section gives the requirements). I might actually end up using windows

Comment: version 5 is available through apt-get and cmake doesn't even check the version anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following commands to install cuda 5 on 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit cmake build-essential
```

Then, extract and cd into the extracted archive and run the following commands to build:

```
mkdir build; cd build
cmake ..
make
```

This will build a bin file called currennt. Place this file in your PATH and you should be good to go.

Checking out the cmake files it looks like it just requires CUDA and not necessarily version 5. It checks for CUDA and does not actually specify a version although version 5 is available through apt-get anyhow.

Comment: Thanks mchid, would upvote but don't not enough karma.

Comment: What do you mean by extracted archive?

Comment: @VivekSubramanian Yes it seems the download for the latest version is available in a deb file for ubuntu (thanks Nvidia!), you can download CUDA 8.0 for Ubuntu 14.04 by running the following command: `wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb' Then, run the following commands to complete the install: `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb` then run: `sudo apt-get update` and finally: `sudo apt-get install cuda`

Comment: @VivekSubramanian If you need for 16.04, run this instead: `wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb` then run: `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb` and then run: `sudo apt-get update` and finally: `sudo apt-get install cuda`

Comment: @VivekSubramanian for more info go to: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and select **Linux** > **x86_64** > **Ubuntu** > and then select your version (**14.04** or **16.04**) > **deb (network)**

Comment: Thank you for your response, @mchid. What I meant was, I was able to successfully run the first two lines (update and install), but I'm not sure what archive you're referring to when you say, "extract and cd into the extracted archive." Where is this archive located?

Comment: @VivekSubramanian Let me explain, there is no archive. The instructions have changed. The install is now available for download from nvidia in the form of a ".deb" file instead of a compressed .tar file. Before, the user would download a compressed .tar file and then uncompress the file which would create an "archive" or a "folder".  The commands listed in the answer no longer apply. See my last few posts for newer instructions on how to install as a .deb file instead. Here is more info on cd command (which is not used to install now but fyi): http://www.linfo.org/cd.html